# Check local (internal) IP with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ip

I know that this will seem like a duplicate, but I honestly have not been able to find any answer that solves this.

I have two iPads set up with static IP addresses on a network that can only access www.example.com (network restriction, not iPad restriction). example.com is an eCommerce site and I want to fill in a coupon field whenever either of these two iPads visit the site.

The only way I can think of doing this is getting the local IP addresses of the iPads (e.g. 192.168.0.x) and creating a whitelist array. But my problem is trying to detect the browsing device's local IP.

I cannot use any resources outside of the example.com domain and I can't use the network's public IP as there will be lots of other devices connected.

Also, I've tried WebRTC but it's Chrome and Firefox only, and I am limited to the iPad's native Safari browser.

Help me Overflow Kenobi, you're my only hope!

**EDIT**

Conditions have changed. I found out that no other devices will be using the checkout service, so I can now target the external IP. Details about how I did this are below.

Comment: java and rtc are the only hacks i've seen to get an IP from JS, which alone doesn't provide such capability.

Comment: I'm open to any options, even if there is a PHP alternative that I can then carry over into JS. Although I have very little experience with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found a solution to my problem.

**One correction first to my original question:**

I just found out that none of the other devices on the network will actually be used for purchasing on the website, so the iPads are the only two devices that will enter the checkout.

Knowing this now, I am able to target the public IP of the network. I've done this using two scripts, one in an external PHP file (our server isn't setup to run PHP in HTML files) and one in an external JavaScript file (easier management as there are multiple versions of the checkout page, so if I need to change the discount code I just have to update the JS file.)

PHP file:

```
// Declare content as JavaScript
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
// Declare variables for IP adress requests
$http_client_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$http_x_forwarded_for = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Request for most accurate IP address
if (!empty($http_client_ip)) {
    $ip_address = $http_client_ip;
} else if (!empty($http_x_forwarded_for)) {
    $ip_address = $http_x_forwarded_for;
} else {
    $ip_address = $remote_addr;
}

// Add results to array - multiple IP addresses may be returned
$list = explode(',', $ip_address, 2);

// Write the first IP address in array as JavaScript
echo 'document.write(\'<div class="myIP" style="display:none;">' . $list[0] . '</div>\')';
```

JS file:

```
// Array of allowed IP addresses
var allowedIP = ['x.x.x.x'];
// Coupon code
var couponCode = "CODE001";

// Run script when page is loaded
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get device IP from 'myIP' div loaded by php
    var ipAddress = $('.myIP').text();
    // Check if device IP matches any of the IPs in the Allowed array
    for (var i = 0; i<allowedIP.length;i++) {
        if (ipAddress == allowedIP[i]) {
            // If it matches, write to console
            console.log("Your external IP is allowed");
            // Add coupon code to input field
            $('input[name="coupon"]').val(couponCode);
        } else {
            // If it does not match, write to console
            console.log("Sorry buddy, you're not on the list.");
        }
    };
});
```